# Swift 4 CloudKit queryCompletionBlock doesn't appear to execute

Tags: swift4, xcode9, cloudkit, ckqueryoperation

I followed several CKQueryOperation examples/narratives on problems to fetch from CloudKit. My table has about 370 rows and 8 columns..at best I can only fetch about 60 rows.  resultsLimit parameter does not seem to help.. My queryCompletionBlock is not executing.  Sometimes I fetch 5 rows and other time 30+  Response from Cloud is quick just now all rows It's got to be some newbie code mistake!

```
func getData() {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: RemoteFunctions.RemoteRecords.booksDB, predicate: predicate)
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.default()
    let privateDatabase = cloudContainer.privateCloudDatabase
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    operation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
    operation.resultsLimit = 20

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord) in
        self.allRecords.append(record)
         print(record)
    }
    operation.queryCompletionBlock = {[weak self] (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) in
        // There is another batch of records to be fetched
        print("completion block called with \(String(describing: cursor))")

        if let cursor = cursor  {
            let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = operation.recordFetchedBlock
            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
           newOperation.resultsLimit = 10
            privateDatabase.add(newOperation)
            print("more records")
        }
            // There was an error
        else if let error = error {
            print("Error:", error)
        }

            // No error and no cursor means the operation was successful
        else {
            print("Finished with records:")
        }
        } as? (CKQueryCursor?, Error?) -> Void
```

//
    privateDatabase.add(operation)

```
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this...

```
func getData(withCursor cursor: CKQueryCursor? = nil)
    {
    let cloudContainer = CKContainer.default()
    let privateDatabase = cloudContainer.privateCloudDatabase

    let operation: CKQueryOperation

    if let cursor = cursor
    {
        operation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
    }
    else
    {
        let operation_configuration: CKOperationConfiguration = CKOperationConfiguration()
        operation_configuration.isLongLived = true
        operation_configuration.qualityOfService = .background

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: RemoteFunctions.RemoteRecords.booksDB, predicate: predicate)

        operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
        operation.configuration = operation_configuration


        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord) in
            self.allRecords.append(record)
                print(record)
        }

        operation.queryCompletionBlock = {[weak self] (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) in
            // There is another batch of records to be fetched
            print("completion block called with \(String(describing: cursor))")

            if let error = error 
            {
                print("Error:", error)
            }
            else if let cursor = cursor  
            {
                self.getData(withCursor: cursor)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Finished with records:")
            }
        }
    }

    privateDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

This is a *recursive* version of your fuction, using the new `CKQueryOperation` API.

It seems that your're loosing reference to the operation object when a cursor arrives.

Comment: Adolfo I tried your code... fetched 13 rows.  None of the messages in the queryCompletionBlock fired?

Comment: Hi @Jake. It's my fault, I had a mistake in my code. I've edited an now it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `as? (CKQueryCursor?, Error?) -> Void` near the end. Be careful not to remove the preceeding brace.

Remove `newOperation.resultsLimit = 10` in your cursor block.

Add `operation = newOperation` immediately above `privateDatabase.add(newOperation)`

Uncomment the `privateDatabase.add(operation)`

That should help. Large fetches, where the cursor block gets hit more than 3 times can be problematic. If you do the above, you should be ok. Some people like to write/call the cursor block as its own function. That works as well, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Brain, I had the  add(operation) commented out for a test...understand that had to be active.  I removed the as? & results limit statements per your suggestion. Still only got back about 30 rows.  I also implemented another version with the cursor block being in it's own function. Copied logic right out of Ray Wenderlich's tutorial  Got up to 130 rows, but to Adolofo's comment maybe I'm losing the reference?  The data is clean best to my knowledge & no errors... it just craps out?

Comment: Adolfo/Brian... thanks for your input.  I'm suspecting a data problem. I imported my two tables to CloudKit  via JSON files.  The small file returns good, in fact I increased the rows by a factor of 3 and all rows return.  On my problem table, I got some weird query errors on CloudKit Dashboard. However no errors returns in Xcode.  I'm going to scrub the data and repopulate the problem table. Will update later. Jake

Comment: Guys, thanks again for your advice.  Looks like I had bad data. Might have been a cut/paste from Excel to the JSON converter.  When I imported from a CSV file and ran the JSON back through my Xcode import to CloudKit, my fetch got all the rows!  My confidence is restored!